# Upload a package to multiple package managers from a single repo

Tags: python, pip, conda, homebrew, package-management

I had created a python package [Categorize-CLI](https://pypi.org/project/Categorize-CLI/) and had uploaded it to `pypi`, the source code of the project is available in Github, is it possible to upload this project to multiple package management systems like `Homebrew` and `Conda` from a single repo or will there be any conflicts?
Or will I have to create separate repositories for each package manager?

Thank you!

Comment: Does one consider the "feedstock" that Conda Forge creates a separate repository? One doesn't create this directly, but instead submits a recipe to [the `staged-recipes` repository](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes), and it generates everything after merging. It mostly maintains itself, automatically detecting PyPI releases and generating Conda builds. https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html#contributing-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to upload this project to multiple package management systems like Homebrew and Conda from a single repo or will there be any conflicts.

Not sure about `Conda`, but for `Homebrew`, it is totally possible and there are some github actions can help with the release process:

- [dawidd6/action-homebrew-bump-formula](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-homebrew-bump-formula)
- [mislav/bump-homebrew-formula-action](https://github.com/mislav/bump-homebrew-formula-action)